# spring-xd how to use source:file read line one by one

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, spring-xd

I have a stream that watch output of multi file in a directory, process data and put it to HDFS. Here is my stream creat command:

```
stream create --name fileHdfs --definition "file --dir=/var/log/supervisor/ --pattern=tracker.out-*.log --outputType=text/plain | logHdfsTransformer | hdfs --fsUri=hdfs://192.168.1.115:8020 --directory=/data/log/appsync --fileName=log --partitionPath=path(dateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd'))" --deploy
```

Problem is source:file module send all data read from file to log processing module instead of one line each turn, becase of that, payload string have millions of char, i can't process it. Ex:

```
--- PAYLOAD LENGTH---- 9511284
```

Please tell me how to read line by line when use source:file module, thanks !!!

Answer (score 3):

It's not currently supported, but it would be easy to write a custom `source` using a Spring Integration `inbound-channel-adapter` to invoke a POJO that reads a line at a time.

Please open a [new feature JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD).

You could also do it with a `job` instead of a `stream` in XD.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this may be late, but for any googlers out there looking for the solution:

Even though there is no module or option that does it automatically, it's as simple as adding a splitter that separates the incoming message into multiple outgoing messages.

Please note that you have to decide between using \n and \r\n. Check your files to see what they're using.

Example:

```
stream create --name filetest --definition "file --outputType=text/plain --dir=/tmp/examplefiles/| splitter --expression=payload.split('\\n') | log" --deploy
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Spring Integration has a FileSplitter that splits a text file into lines. You can use this to create a custom processor module, let's call it file-split:

1. Create file-split.xml file with the following content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans        
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd">

   <int:splitter input-channel="input" output-channel="output">
           <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.splitter.FileSplitter">
                   <constructor-arg value="false"/>
           </bean>
   </int:splitter>

   <int:channel id="output"/> 
   </beans>
   ```
2. Copy the file to ${XD_HOME}/xd/modules/processor/file-split/config/ (create the path if needed)
3. Sample usage:

   ```
   stream create --name splitFile --definition "file --dir=/data --ref=true | file-split | log" --deploy
   ```

You can further customize the module to take more options if needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the **--mode=lines** option while deploying the stream. 
Please check below documentation reference : http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#file

Hope this helps!

Cheers, 
Pratik